# Repeater Not showing any data in asp.net application on hosting server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using repeater which works fine on local system but not working when uploaded on web server. And its also working fine when connected to the server from our local code..
The following is the page code and code behind. And repeated contains textbox, dropdown list which loads dynamically at the run time

page code:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="UC_TopicSchedulingNew.ascx.cs" Inherits="Scheduling_UC_TopicSchedulingNew" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="XtendedControls" Namespace="XtendedControls" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<%@ Register Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajax" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/SelectPopup/UC_PopupDropdown.ascx" TagName="PopupSelectAny" TagPrefix="PD" %>
<script type="text/javascript">
function pageLoad() {
    $('.DatepickerInput').datepicker({ changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: '1950:2050', dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', showButtonPanel: true });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.DatepickerInput').datepicker({ changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: '1950:2050', dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', showButtonPanel: true });
});
</script>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updtsForm">
<ContentTemplate>
    <div style="width: 100%; float: left; padding-left: 10px;">
        <div style="width: 20%; float: left; padding-left: 10px;">
            <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold;">
                Branch : <b style="color: Red;">*</b>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtBranchs" runat="server" CssClass="txt-drop-down" TabIndex="1"
                    ReadOnly="true" Width="16px"></asp:TextBox><cc1:XBranch ID="XBranch" runat="server"
                        TabIndex="-1"></cc1:XBranch>
                <ajax:PopupControlExtender ID="PopExBranchs" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtBranchs"
                    BehaviorID="exbranchClose" PopupControlID="pnlListBranchs" CommitProperty="value"
                    Position="Bottom" OffsetY="2" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="HFBranchID" runat="server" />
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold;">
                Course : <b style="color: Red;">*</b>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCourse" runat="server" CssClass="txt-drop-down" TabIndex="2"
                    ReadOnly="true" Width="16px"></asp:TextBox><cc1:XCourse ID="XCourse" runat="server"
                        TabIndex="-1"></cc1:XCourse>
                <ajax:PopupControlExtender ID="PopExCourse" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtCourse"
                    BehaviorID="excourseClose" PopupControlID="pnlListCourse" CommitProperty="value"
                    Position="Bottom" OffsetY="2" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="HFCourseID" runat="server" />
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold;">
                Batch :
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtBatch" runat="server" CssClass="txt-drop-down" TabIndex="44"
                    ReadOnly="true" Width="16px"></asp:TextBox><cc1:XTextBox ID="XBatch" runat="server"
                        TabIndex="-1"></cc1:XTextBox>
                <ajax:PopupControlExtender ID="PopExBatch" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtBatch"
                    BehaviorID="exBatchClose" PopupControlID="pnlListBatch" CommitProperty="value"
                    Position="Bottom" OffsetY="2" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="HFBatchID" runat="server" Value="0" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="HFBatchClRoom" runat="server" />
            </div>
            <br />
        </div>
        <div style="width: 20%; float: left; padding-left: 10px;">
            <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold;">
                Time :
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <cc1:XTextBox ID="XTime" runat="server" TabIndex="-1" Width="149px"></cc1:XTextBox>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold;">
                Start Date :
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <cc1:XTextBox ID="XStartDate" runat="server" TabIndex="-1" Width="149px"></cc1:XTextBox>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold;">
                End Date :
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <cc1:XTextBox ID="XEndDate" runat="server" TabIndex="-1" Width="149px"></cc1:XTextBox>
            </div>
            <br />
        </div>
        <div style="width: 50%; float: left; padding-left: 10px;">
            <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold;">
                Curriculum :
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCurriculum" runat="server" CssClass="txt-drop-down" TabIndex="44"
                    ReadOnly="true" Width="16px"></asp:TextBox><cc1:XCurriculum ID="XCurriculum" runat="server"
                        TabIndex="-1"></cc1:XCurriculum>
                <ajax:PopupControlExtender ID="popExCurriculum" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtCurriculum"
                    BehaviorID="exCurriculumClose" PopupControlID="pnlListCurriculum" CommitProperty="value"
                    Position="Bottom" OffsetY="2" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="HFCurriculumID" runat="server" Value="0" />
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold;">
                Faculty :
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFaculty" runat="server" CssClass="txt-drop-down" TabIndex="44"
                    ReadOnly="true" Width="16px"></asp:TextBox><cc1:XFaculty ID="XFaculty" runat="server"
                        TabIndex="-1"></cc1:XFaculty>
                <ajax:PopupControlExtender ID="PopExFaculty" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtFaculty"
                    BehaviorID="exFacultyClose" PopupControlID="pnlListFaculty" CommitProperty="value"
                    Position="Bottom" OffsetY="2" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="HFFacultyID" runat="server" Value="0" />
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold;">
                <asp:Button ID="btnGet" runat="server" Text="Get Topics" 
                    onclick="btnGet_Click" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <b>Topics : </b>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div style="width: 100%; float: left; height: 250px; overflow: scroll; border: solid 1px gray;">
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptTopics" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table class="grid-new" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="table1">
                    <thead>
                        <th class="myheadth" style="text-align: left; width: 40px;">
                            Srno.
                        </th>
                        <th class="myheadth" style="text-align: left; width: 300px;">
                            Topic
                        </th>
                        <th class="myheadth" style="text-align: left; width: 80px;">
                            Topic Date
                        </th>
                        <th class="myheadth" style="text-align: left; width: 60px;">
                            St. Time
                        </th>
                        <th class="myheadth" style="text-align: left; width: 60px;">
                            En. Time
                        </th>
                        <th class="myheadth" style="text-align: left;">
                            Classroom
                        </th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: left; width: 40px;">
                        <%#Container.ItemIndex+1 %>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: left; width: 300px;">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ID")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                        <%#Eval("TopicName")%>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: left; width: 80px;">
                        <div id="DatepickerDiv" class="demo">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtTopicDate" runat="server" CssClass="DatepickerInput" Font-Names="Verdana"
                                TabIndex="5" Font-Size="11px" Width="70px" Style="border: solid 1px gray;"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: left; width: 60px;">
                        <cc1:XStartTime ID="XStartTime" runat="server" Width="50px"></cc1:XStartTime>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: left; width: 60px;">
                        <cc1:XEndTime ID="XEndTime" runat="server" Width="50px"></cc1:XEndTime>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: left;">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlListView" runat="server">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </tbody> </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
    <div style="width:100%; float:left; padding-top:20px;">
        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" Width="70px" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
    </div>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updPanels">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlListBranchs" runat="server" BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black"
        Width="300px" Height="250px" ScrollBars="Vertical" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px"
        BorderColor="Gray">
        <PD:PopupSelectAny ID="pdBranchs" runat="server" />
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlListCourse" runat="server" BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black"
        Width="300px" Height="250px" ScrollBars="Vertical" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px"
        BorderColor="Gray">
        <PD:PopupSelectAny ID="pdCourse" runat="server" />
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlListBatch" runat="server" BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" Width="300px"
        Height="250px" ScrollBars="Vertical" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="Gray">
        <PD:PopupSelectAny ID="pdBatch" runat="server" />
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlListCurriculum" runat="server" BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black"
        Width="300px" Height="250px" ScrollBars="Vertical" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px"
        BorderColor="Gray">
        <PD:PopupSelectAny ID="pdCurriculum" runat="server" />
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlListFaculty" runat="server" BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black"
        Width="300px" Height="250px" ScrollBars="Vertical" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px"
        BorderColor="Gray">
        <PD:PopupSelectAny ID="pdFaculty" runat="server" />
    </asp:Panel>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;

public partial class Scheduling_UC_TopicSchedulingNew : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
delegate void dlgTsBranchs();
delegate void dlgTsClassrooms();
delegate void dlgTsCourses();
delegate void dlgTsBatches();
delegate void dlgTsCurriculums();
delegate void dlgTsFaculties();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.pdBranchs.dlgSelectRecords += new dlgSelectRecords(pdBranchs_dlgSelectRecords);
    dlgTsBranchs dlgTsBranchs = new dlgTsBranchs(getBranchs);
    this.pdBranchs.PageMethodWithListRecords = dlgTsBranchs;

    this.pdCourse.dlgSelectRecords += new dlgSelectRecords(pdCourse_dlgSelectRecords);
    dlgTsCourses dlgTsCourses = new dlgTsCourses(getCourses);
    this.pdCourse.PageMethodWithListRecords = dlgTsCourses;

    this.pdFaculty.dlgSelectRecords += new dlgSelectRecords(pdFaculty_dlgSelectRecords);
    dlgTsFaculties dlgTsFaculties = new dlgTsFaculties(getFaculties);
    this.pdFaculty.PageMethodWithListRecords = dlgTsFaculties;

    this.pdBatch.dlgSelectRecords += new dlgSelectRecords(pdBatch_dlgSelectRecords);
    dlgTsBatches dlgAdBatches = new dlgTsBatches(getBatches);
    this.pdBatch.PageMethodWithListRecords = dlgAdBatches;

    this.pdCurriculum.dlgSelectRecords += new dlgSelectRecords(pdCurriculum_dlgSelectRecords);
    dlgTsCurriculums dlgTsCurriculums = new dlgTsCurriculums(getCurriculum);
    this.pdCurriculum.PageMethodWithListRecords = dlgTsCurriculums;

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        disbleEnterKeyForTextBoxes();
    }
}

public void disbleEnterKeyForTextBoxes()
{
    XTime.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "return (event.keyCode!=13);");
}

void pdFaculty_dlgSelectRecords(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e, string selval)
{
    String[] Myvals = selval.Split('\t');
    XFaculty.Text = Myvals[0].ToString();
    HFFacultyID.Value = Myvals[1].ToString();
    PopExFaculty.Cancel();
}

void pdCurriculum_dlgSelectRecords(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e, string selval)
{
    String[] Myvals = selval.Split('\t');
    XCurriculum.Text = Myvals[0].ToString();
    HFCurriculumID.Value = Myvals[1].ToString();
    popExCurriculum.Cancel();
    getFaculties();
    XFaculty.Text = "";
    HFFacultyID.Value = "0";
    rptTopics.DataSource = null;
    rptTopics.DataBind();
}

void pdBatch_dlgSelectRecords(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e, string selval)
{
    String[] Myvals = selval.Split('\t');
    XBatch.Text = Myvals[0].ToString();
    HFBatchID.Value = Myvals[1].ToString();
    PopExBatch.Cancel();
    Models.Batch objBatch = new BLL.Batch().OpenByID(HFBatchID.Value);
    XTime.Text = objBatch.Time;
    XStartDate.Text = objBatch.StDate;
    XEndDate.Text = objBatch.EnDate;
    HFBatchClRoom.Value = objBatch.ClassRoomID.ToString();
    getCurriculum();
    XCurriculum.Text = "";
    HFCurriculumID.Value = "0";
    XFaculty.Text = "";
    HFFacultyID.Value = "0";
    rptTopics.DataSource = null;
    rptTopics.DataBind();
}

void pdCourse_dlgSelectRecords(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e, string selval)
{
    String[] Myvals = selval.Split('\t');
    XCourse.Text = Myvals[0].ToString();
    HFCourseID.Value = Myvals[1].ToString();
    PopExCourse.Cancel();
    XBatch.Text = "";
    HFBatchID.Value = "0";
    XTime.Text = "";
    XStartDate.Text = "";
    XEndDate.Text = "";
    getBatches();
    XCurriculum.Text = "";
    HFCurriculumID.Value = "0";
    XFaculty.Text = "";
    HFFacultyID.Value = "0";
    rptTopics.DataSource = null;
    rptTopics.DataBind();
}


void pdBranchs_dlgSelectRecords(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e, string selval)
{
    String[] Myvals = selval.Split('\t');
    XBranch.Text = Myvals[0].ToString();
    HFBranchID.Value = Myvals[1].ToString();
    PopExBranchs.Cancel();
    getCourses();
    XCourse.Text = "";
    HFCourseID.Value = "0";
    XBatch.Text = "";
    HFBatchID.Value = "0";
    XTime.Text = "";
    XStartDate.Text = "";
    XEndDate.Text = "";
    XCurriculum.Text = "";
    HFCurriculumID.Value = "0";
    XFaculty.Text = "";
    HFFacultyID.Value = "0";
    rptTopics.DataSource = null;
    rptTopics.DataBind();
}

public void getBranchs()
{
    try
    {
        Type newClass = typeof(PopupListSelect.Branch);
        Repeater nlpListview = (Repeater)pdBranchs.FindControl("gvpbList");
        object created = Activator.CreateInstance(newClass, Session["User"].ToString(), Session["DesigID"].ToString(), nlpListview);
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}

public void getCourses()
{
    try
    {
        Type newClass = typeof(PopupListSelect.Course);
        Repeater nlpListview = (Repeater)pdCourse.FindControl("gvpbList");
        object created = Activator.CreateInstance(newClass, HFBranchID.Value, nlpListview);
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}

public void getBatches()
{
    try
    {
        if (Session["DesigID"].Equals("6") || Session["DesigID"].Equals("7"))
        {
            Type newClass = typeof(PopupListSelect.Batch);
            Repeater nlpListview = (Repeater)pdBatch.FindControl("gvpbList");
            object created = Activator.CreateInstance(newClass, HFBranchID.Value, HFCourseID.Value, Session["User"].ToString(), nlpListview);
        }
        else
        {
            Type newClass = typeof(PopupListSelect.Batch);
            Repeater nlpListview = (Repeater)pdBatch.FindControl("gvpbList");
            object created = Activator.CreateInstance(newClass, HFBranchID.Value, HFCourseID.Value, nlpListview);
        }
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}

public void getCurriculum()
{
    try
    {
        Type newClass = typeof(PopupListSelect.Curriculum);
        Repeater nlpListview = (Repeater)pdCurriculum.FindControl("gvpbList");
        object created = Activator.CreateInstance(newClass, nlpListview, HFBatchID.Value);
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}

public void getFaculties()
{
    try
    {
        Type newClass = typeof(PopupListSelect.Faculties);
        Repeater nlpListview = (Repeater)pdFaculty.FindControl("gvpbList");
        object created = Activator.CreateInstance(newClass, HFBranchID.Value, HFCurriculumID.Value, HFBatchID.Value, nlpListview);
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}

public void getTopics()
{
    try
    {
        Type newClass = typeof(PopupListSelect.Topics);
        object created = Activator.CreateInstance(newClass, HFCurriculumID.Value, rptTopics);

        String[] TimeVals = XTime.Text.Split('-');
        foreach (RepeaterItem itm in rptTopics.Items)
        {
            TextBox XStartTime = (TextBox)itm.FindControl("XStartTime");
            TextBox XEndTime = (TextBox)itm.FindControl("XEndTime");
            DropDownList ddlListView = (DropDownList)itm.FindControl("ddlListView");

            XStartTime.Text = TimeVals[0].ToString().Trim();
            XEndTime.Text = TimeVals[1].ToString().Trim();

            try
            {
                newClass = typeof(PopupListSelect.Classrooms);
                created = Activator.CreateInstance(newClass, Int32.Parse(HFBranchID.Value), ddlListView);
                ddlListView.SelectedValue = HFBatchClRoom.Value;
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }


    }
    catch
    {

    }
}

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataColumn dc;
    DataRow dr;

    dc = new DataColumn();
    dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
    dc.ColumnName = "BranchID";
    dc.Unique = false;
    dt.Columns.Add(dc);

    dc = new DataColumn();
    dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
    dc.ColumnName = "CourseID";
    dc.Unique = false;
    dt.Columns.Add(dc);

    dc = new DataColumn();
    dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
    dc.ColumnName = "BatchID";
    dc.Unique = false;
    dt.Columns.Add(dc);

    dc = new DataColumn();
    dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
    dc.ColumnName = "CurriID";
    dc.Unique = false;
    dt.Columns.Add(dc);

    dc = new DataColumn();
    dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
    dc.ColumnName = "TopicID";
    dc.Unique = false;
    dt.Columns.Add(dc);

    dc = new DataColumn();
    dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
    dc.ColumnName = "TopicDate";
    dc.Unique = false;
    dt.Columns.Add(dc);

    dc = new DataColumn();
    dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
    dc.ColumnName = "StartTime";
    dc.Unique = false;
    dt.Columns.Add(dc);

    dc = new DataColumn();
    dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
    dc.ColumnName = "EndTime";
    dc.Unique = false;
    dt.Columns.Add(dc);

    dc = new DataColumn();
    dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
    dc.ColumnName = "ClassroomID";
    dc.Unique = false;
    dt.Columns.Add(dc);

    dc = new DataColumn();
    dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
    dc.ColumnName = "FacultyID";
    dc.Unique = false;
    dt.Columns.Add(dc);

    foreach (RepeaterItem itm in rptTopics.Items)
    {
        TextBox XStartTime = (TextBox)itm.FindControl("XStartTime");
        TextBox XEndTime = (TextBox)itm.FindControl("XEndTime");
        DropDownList ddlListView = (DropDownList)itm.FindControl("ddlListView");
        TextBox txtTopicDate = (TextBox)itm.FindControl("txtTopicDate");
        Label lblID = (Label)itm.FindControl("lblID");
        if (!txtTopicDate.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["BranchID"] = Int32.Parse(HFBranchID.Value);
            dr["CourseID"] = Int32.Parse(HFCourseID.Value);
            dr["BatchID"] = Int32.Parse(HFBatchID.Value);
            dr["CurriID"] = Int32.Parse(HFCurriculumID.Value);
            dr["TopicID"] = Int32.Parse(lblID.Text);
            dr["TopicDate"] = new Common.GeneralFunctions().ConvertDate_MM_DD_YY(txtTopicDate.Text.Trim());
            dr["StartTime"] = XStartTime.Text;
            dr["EndTime"] = XEndTime.Text;
            dr["ClassroomID"] = Int32.Parse(ddlListView.SelectedValue);
            dr["FacultyID"] = HFFacultyID.Value;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
    }

    TopicScheduling.ScheduledTopics.XMLSaveTopicsToSchedule(dt);
    Response.Redirect("~/Topic-Scheduling");
}

protected void btnGet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    getTopics();
    //new BLL.Sch().Topics(Int32.Parse(HFBranchID.Value), Int32.Parse(HFCourseID.Value), Int32.Parse(HFBatchID.Value), Int32.Parse(HFCurriculumID.Value),HFFacultyID.Value,rptTopics);
    Models.ScheduledTopics obj = new Models.ScheduledTopics();
    obj.BranchID = Int32.Parse(HFBranchID.Value);
    obj.CourseID = Int32.Parse(HFCourseID.Value);
    obj.BatchID = Int32.Parse(HFBatchID.Value);
    obj.CurriID = Int32.Parse(HFCurriculumID.Value);
    List<Models.ScheduledTopics> objCollect = TopicScheduling.ScheduledTopics.ScheduledTopicsList(obj);

    foreach (RepeaterItem itm in rptTopics.Items)
    {
        TextBox XStartTime = (TextBox)itm.FindControl("XStartTime");
        TextBox XEndTime = (TextBox)itm.FindControl("XEndTime");
        DropDownList ddlListView = (DropDownList)itm.FindControl("ddlListView");
        TextBox txtTopicDate = (TextBox)itm.FindControl("txtTopicDate");
        Label lblID = (Label)itm.FindControl("lblID");
        for (int i = 0; i <= objCollect.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (objCollect[i].TopicID.ToString().Equals(lblID.Text))
            {
                XStartTime.Text = objCollect[i].StartTime;
                XEndTime.Text = objCollect[i].EndTime;
                txtTopicDate.Text = objCollect[i].TopicDate;
                ddlListView.SelectedValue = objCollect[i].ClassroomID.ToString();
                if (!HFFacultyID.Value.Equals(objCollect[i].FacultyID))
                {
                    txtTopicDate.Enabled = false;
                    XStartTime.Enabled = false;
                    XEndTime.Enabled = false;
                    ddlListView.Enabled = false;
                    txtTopicDate.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                }
                else
                {
                    txtTopicDate.Enabled = true;
                    XStartTime.Enabled = true;
                    XEndTime.Enabled = true;
                    ddlListView.Enabled = true;
                    txtTopicDate.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Yo mut ensure you have trust connection from your web server and your database server. i suggest you to ping database server from your web server,

For dignostic i suggest you also to read event log from your web server